# Is my target selection AI efficient?

Tags: android, ios, optimization, unity-game-engine

quick question. I am developing a top-down 2d Platformer game with lots of enemies in the map (at least a hundred spawn at the start of each level). Each enemy uses an AI that searches the map for objects with a specified tag, sorts each object into a list based on their distance, then reacts to the object closest to them.

My code works, but the thing is, if the machine my game is running on is slow, then my game lags. I want to be able to port my game to Android and iOS with low end specs.

In pursuit of putting less strain on the CPU, is there a better way to write my AI?

Here is my code:

```
void Start () {

    FoodTargets = new List<Transform>(); // my list
    SelectedTarget = null; // the target the enemy reacts to
    myTransform = transform; 
    AddAllFood ();

}

public void AddAllFood()
{

    GameObject[] Foods = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Object");
    foreach (GameObject enemy in Foods)
        AddTarget (enemy.transform);

}

public void AddTarget(Transform enemy)
{
    if (enemy.GetComponent<ClassRatingScript>().classrating != 1) { // classrating is an attribute each enemy has that determines their identity (like if they are a plant, a herbivore or a carnivore)
        FoodTargets.Add (enemy); // adds the object to the list
    }
}


private void SortTargetsByDistance() // this is how I sort according to distance, is this the fastest and most efficient way to do this?
{
    FoodTargets.Sort (delegate(Transform t1, Transform t2) { 
        return Vector3.Distance(t1.position, myTransform.position).CompareTo(Vector3.Distance(t2.position, myTransform.position));
    });
}

private void TargetEnemy() // this is called every 4 frames
{
    if (SelectedTarget == null) {
        SortTargetsByDistance ();
        SelectedTarget = FoodTargets [1];
    } 
    else {
        SortTargetsByDistance ();
        SelectedTarget = FoodTargets [1];
    }
}

                if (optimizer <= 2) { // this is a variable that increments every frame and resets to 0 on the 3rd frame. Only every 3rd frame is the target enemy method is called.
                    optimizer++;
                } else {
                    TargetEnemy ();

// the rest are attributes that the AI considers when reacting to their target

                    targetmass = SelectedTarget.GetComponent<MassScript> ().mass;
                    targetclass = SelectedTarget.GetComponent<ClassRatingScript> ().classrating;
                    mass = this.GetComponent<MassScript> ().mass;
                    classrating = this.GetComponent<ClassRatingScript> ().classrating;
                    distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, SelectedTarget.transform.position);

                    optimizer = 0;
                }
```

Is there a more optimized way of doing this? Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How often are you sorting the targets by distance? and are you doing the sort for every single enemy? (100 * object count arrays being sorted?)

Comment: The method for adding objects to the list is called when the enemy is spawned. Then the method for sorting objects in the list according to distance is called every 4 frames. Each enemy on the map does this only if they are inside the camera bounds. If they are outside the camera they don't do anything.

Comment: What is the playable fps of the game?

Comment: I have it set to 0.025 so that must mean 40 frames per second. I am using FixedUpdate for this. What would you recommend for mobile games? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Hmm, Will the targets be moving much/at all? The cause of the lag is likely to the sorting of so many objects in so many arrays. If they have a small movement area, then you may be able to ignore a large portion of the targets and have smaller arrays to sort, meaning fewer comparisons and less cpu time needed.

Comment: The targets are constantly trying to attack each other based on the their stats. But they only activate while they are inside the camera's bounds. Is that what you mean by movement area? Also im wondering if the delegates I used in my sorting method are slow.

Comment: What I meant was, consider the likelihood that an enemy will end up fighting its nth (25th 50th 100th) nearest neighbour. If the chance of that happening is low, then is there a need to have the target array being that large? I'm not entirely sure if there is a better way of sorting via distance, but sorting n arrays of size n will be quite bad. Eg (if it was using quick sort you would have average complexity of O(n*(n*log(n))) and n^3 worst case I think. Which you are doing 10 times a second on n = over a hundred.

Comment: Then compound that with the overhead of the Vector3.Distance calculations * every comparison in the sort.

Comment: I'll consider your insights. Thanks for the time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not awfully familiar with C# or Unity but I would look very carefully at what sorting algorithm your sorting method is using. If all you want is the closest Game Object, then sorting isn't necessary.

The fastest sorting algorithms, such as [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), are `O(n*log(n))`. That is to say that the time it takes to sort a collection of `n` objects is bounded by some constant multiple of `n*log(n)`. If you just want the `k` closest objects, where `k << n`, then you can perform `k` iterations of the [Bubble Sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). This will have time-complexity `O(k*n)`, which is much better then before.

However, if you only need the single closest object, then just find the closest object without sorting (pseudocode):

```
float smallestDistance = Inf;
object closestObject = null;
foreach object in objectsWithTag {
    float d = distance(object, enemy);
    if (d < smallestDistance) {
        smallestDistance = d;
        closestObject = object;
    }
}
```

This extremely simple algorithm has time complexity `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Let me give this a try. Cheers.